# find the probability of a spade from a five-card deck

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to solve a simple exercise from a probability book but I have no idea how. 
Given a five-card deck containing: ace of spades, king of spades, king of hearts, queen of spades, and queen of hearts, there are 2 players and each one has exactly one card. You observe evidence that one player has a picture card (king or queen). What’s the probability that the other player has a spade?

I think at conditional probabilities, but I don't know how to model this events. P(A|B) where A is the event of extracting a spade and B represents event of having a spade from a picture card. I know that if I observe picture card than the probability of being a spade is 1/2.

Comment: How many cards does each player hold?  Did we see the rank of all of the one players' cards, or just that one?

Comment: It matters how the cards are split up among the players.  Consider the extreme example of where the youngest player is *always* given *all* of the cards.  In such a scenario, it is impossible for the older player to hold a spade (*or in fact any card at all*).  Consider the other extreme where for each card a coin is flipped.  If heads was flipped the first player gets the card.  If tails, then the second player gets the card.  Consider a third example where the first player is always dealt the top two cards and the second player gets the remaining three. These all have different final answers

Comment: each player has exact one card. All that I know is that one of them has a picture card. (it can be spade or not). I have to find probability that the other player has a spade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Taking your "All that I know..." means that a random card "opened" is seen to be a face card,

either it is a spade face card (Pr = ?) in which case the other card has a Pr of $\frac14$ of being a spade,

or it is a non-spade face card (Pr = ?) in which case the other card has  Pr of $\frac24$ of being a spade

Can you now frame it in terms of conditional probabilities, and apply the law of total probability ?

Comment: $$Pr(A) = Pr(A|B) * P(B) + Pr(A|C) * P(C) $$ where A is the event of having a spade, B if "open" card is a spade and C if "open" card is not a spade. $$Pr(B) = \frac{1}{2}, Pr(A|B) = \frac{2}{4}, Pr(C) = \frac{1}{2}, Pr(A|C) = \frac{3}{4}$$ thus resulting $$Pr(A) = \frac{2} {8} + \frac{3}{8} = \frac{5}{8}$$.